# Lightning Component Visibility filter to check if value is null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visibility, null

How can I set a Lightning Component visibility based on text filed value = NULL. I have a text area field and I want to only display one component if Text area field contains value. I can't seem to be able to find documentation that explains checking value for NULL.

I have looked at this [Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5) but that doesn't have information I need.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to render text area based on some user input>

Comment: @Samir  Yes, That is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the empty string value `''`:

[image]

Comment: Just wondering as the answer of @Samir (the one below) can do the trick too, what will be best practice in general, using this filter or using the code <aura:if ...

Comment: @manza Coding this in to the component means you have to deploy code each time you make a change. If all you want are filters, you probably want to do it this way.

Answer (score 13):

use `<aura:if>` to render the component based on the input of the text area.
Pseudo code.

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="strTest" type="String"/>

  <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.strTest))}">
  //TRUE - show your component here
  <aura:set attribute="else">
   False
  </aura:set>
 </aura:if> 

</aura:component
```

Comment: Can someone please explain how to implement this solution? The UI shown in OP's question does not allow code editing.

Comment: This code can not be used with what was shown in UI. To put a visibility using the UI, refer to sfdxfox's answer above